# glGetProgramIv claims that shader linking failed, but glGetProgramInfoLog is empty

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl-2, glew

I am currently attempting to write a basic graphics engine with OpenGl and C++. In doing so, OpenGl is behaving in a very strange way with no apparent explanation. It claims that a shader failed to compile, but then refuses to give any sort of error explaining why. Specifically, when I call `glGetProgramiv` the returned value is 0, but `glGetProgramInfoLog` gives an empty string¹.

Here is a minimum complete verifiable example:

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <fstream>

GLuint loadShader(const std::string &path, GLenum type);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    //show window & other housekeeping
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_RED_SIZE, 8);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_GREEN_SIZE, 8);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_BLUE_SIZE, 8);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_ALPHA_SIZE, 8);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_BUFFER_SIZE, 32);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, 1);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, 3);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, 3);
    SDL_Window *window = SDL_CreateWindow("test window", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 800, 600, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL | SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE);
    SDL_GLContext glContext = SDL_GL_CreateContext(window);
    SDL_GL_MakeCurrent(window, glContext);
    GLenum c = glewInit();
    if(c != GLEW_OK){
        std::ostringstream sout;
        sout << "Failed to initialize OpenGl: " << glewGetErrorString(c);
        throw std::runtime_error(sout.str());
    }

    //**** -- BEGIN IMPORTANT BIT -- ****//
    //This is where the shaders are loaded

    //load shaders
    GLuint vertexShader = loadShader("shader.vert", GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    GLuint fragmentShader = loadShader("shader.frag", GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

    //create & link program
    GLuint program = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(program, vertexShader);
    glAttachShader(program, fragmentShader);
    glLinkProgram(program);

    //check for errors
    GLint success;
    glGetProgramiv(program, GL_LINK_STATUS, &success);
    if(!success){
        GLchar infoLog[512];
        GLint size; //gives 0 when checked in debugger
        glGetProgramInfoLog(program, 512, &size, infoLog);
        throw std::runtime_error(std::string("Failed to link shader program: ") + infoLog);
    }

    //cleanup
    glDeleteShader(vertexShader);
    glDeleteShader(fragmentShader);

    //**** -- END IMPORTANT BIT -- ****//

    //update loop
    bool isClosed = false;
    while(!isClosed){
        SDL_GL_SwapWindow(window);

        SDL_Event e;
        while(SDL_PollEvent(&e)){
            switch(e.type){
                case SDL_QUIT:
                    isClosed = true;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}

GLuint loadShader(const std::string &path, GLenum type){
    //load file
    std::ifstream fin(path);
    std::string line, total = "";

    while(std::getline(fin, line)){
        total += (line + "\n");
    }

    //reformat source into OpenGl's ridiculous format
    const char *cArray = total.c_str();
    const char **pointerToCArray = &cArray;

    //create shader
    GLuint shader = glCreateShader(type);
    glShaderSource(shader, 1, pointerToCArray, nullptr);
    glCompileShader(shader);

    //check for erros
    GLint success;
    glGetShaderiv(shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
    if(!success){
        GLchar infoLog[512];
        glGetShaderInfoLog(shader, 512, nullptr, infoLog);
        throw std::runtime_error(std::string("Failed to compile shader: ") + infoLog);
    }
}
```

MCVE testshader.vert:

```
#version 330 core

layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(position.x, position.y, position.z, 1.0);
}
```

MCVE testshader.frag:

```
#version 330 core

out vec4 color;

void main()
{
    color = vec4(1.0f, 0.5f, 0.2f, 1.0f);
}
```

When I run this I get the following output in addition to a brief flash of a window:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  Failed to link shader program: 
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Extra Notes:

- I am using Ubuntu 16.10 x64
- I am using a Nvidia GTX 1070 with driver version 375.39
- The SDL and glew versions are those installed from the `libsdl2-dev` and `libglew-dev` packages respectively. I am using pkg-config to link.

During my research to solve this error I mostly found various forum and StackOverflow posts that found specific errors in other people's code. None of these apply to my code, and after finding this error I compared my code to [this](https://learnopengl.com/code_viewer.php?code=getting-started/hellotriangle2) supposedly working example. This example also compiles and runs correctly on my computer, which rules out any sort of configuration error.

¹: It is not possible that `glGetProgramInfoLog` is doing nothing with external consequences and that the `infoLog` array happened to be allocated with a null-terminator character at its first address because the size return of `glGetProgramInfoLog` returns 0 even if set to a different value before `glGetProgramInfoLog` is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the issue: a missing return statement in the loadShader() method. This, however, as I experienced when attempting to solve this was not helpful. As such, I recommend to any future person reading this that you find a working example (ie. [this](https://learnopengl.com/code_viewer.php?code=getting-started/hellotriangle2) one) that does something similar as what you are trying to do and copy/paste progressively smaller parts of its code into yours (or visa-versa) to do a kind of binary search to find your error.

Comment: Warnings enabled with `-Wall -Wextra` would've helped you.

Comment: Are you sure? This is for *shader* linking, not c++ linking.

Comment: @Luther his issue was with his c++. so yes. he's sure. ;) "missing return statement in the loadShader()" the c++ compiler could've warned him about that.